# Leap controller lost while changing screens [LeapMotion AS3]

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, leap-motion

This is the general context.

In a **Main.as** I load a container which load a **Intro screen**.
This **Intro screen** has the first Leapmotion interaction (a simple click on a button) which loads a new screen controlled with more Leapmotion´s gestures.

In the first call, the controller behaves nice, but when I click on the button and the new screen loads, the controller "disconnects" and no more gestures are recognized.

EDITED
I made a new "universal" controller for all the screens, this is the UController class:

Here´s my controller setup:

```
package {   
import com.leapmotion.leap.Controller;
import com.leapmotion.leap.events.LeapEvent;
import com.leapmotion.leap.Frame;
import com.leapmotion.leap.Hand;
import com.leapmotion.leap.Finger;
import com.leapmotion.leap.Vector3;
import com.leapmotion.leap.util.LeapUtil;
import com.leapmotion.leap.Gesture;
import com.leapmotion.leap.SwipeGesture;
import com.leapmotion.leap.ScreenTapGesture;
import com.leapmotion.leap.CircleGesture;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import com.leapmotion.leap.Pointable;
//import com.leapmotion.leap.Config;


public class UController extends MovieClip {

    public var myController:Controller = new Controller();

    public function UController() {
        myController.addEventListener( LeapEvent.LEAPMOTION_INIT, onInit );
        myController.addEventListener( LeapEvent.LEAPMOTION_CONNECTED, onConnected );
        myController.addEventListener( LeapEvent.LEAPMOTION_DISCONNECTED, onDisconnect );
        myController.addEventListener( LeapEvent.LEAPMOTION_EXIT, onExit );
        myController.addEventListener( LeapEvent.LEAPMOTION_FRAME, onFrame );
    }




    public function onInit(e:LeapEvent):void{
        trace("leap init");
    }

    public function onConnected(e:LeapEvent):void {

        myController.enableGesture( Gesture.TYPE_SWIPE );
        //if(myController.config().setFloat("Gesture.Swipe.MinLength", 200.0) && myController.config().setFloat("Gesture.Swipe.MinVelocity", 500)) myController.config().save();
        myController.enableGesture( Gesture.TYPE_CIRCLE );
        myController.enableGesture( Gesture.TYPE_SCREEN_TAP );
        //if(myController.config().setFloat("Gesture.ScreenTap.MinForwardVelocity", 30.0) && myController.config().setFloat("Gesture.ScreenTap.HistorySeconds", .5) && myController.config().setFloat("Gesture.ScreenTap.MinDistance", 1.0)) myController.config().save();
        trace("leap connected");

    }

    public function onDisconnect(e:LeapEvent):void{
        trace("leap disconnected");
    }

    public function onExit(e:LeapEvent):void{
        trace("leap exit");
    }

    public static function onFrame(e:LeapEvent):void{
        trace("leap frame");
    }

}


}
```

In my game screens I only provide the onFrame() function...and it works, but the same behavior is repeated when I try to use the whole screens as a complete applicaction.

Only the first screen works, then the controller stops working when a second screen is loaded (via Loader()).

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one LeapMotion controller present try creating one controller that sits in parent scope of your UI screens - Main.as for instance - that way you don't waste resources on creating new instances, so your application will work faster.

And your problem sounds like lost listeners to events - are you adding them on each new instantation of the controller?

According to library's documentation [DOCS](https://github.com/logotype/LeapMotionAS3) we have the following code to connect to the controller:

```
controller = new Controller();
controller.addEventListener( LeapEvent.LEAPMOTION_INIT, onInit );
controller.addEventListener( LeapEvent.LEAPMOTION_CONNECTED, onConnect );
controller.addEventListener( LeapEvent.LEAPMOTION_DISCONNECTED, onDisconnect );
controller.addEventListener( LeapEvent.LEAPMOTION_EXIT, onExit );
controller.addEventListener( LeapEvent.LEAPMOTION_FRAME, onFrame );
```

Of course, functions onInit, onConnect must be created by you. Function onFrame will be invoked repeatedly giving information on Controller state. onFrame will receive a Frame object with strongly typed (meaning defined object type) properties.

Comment: I tried to use listeners, but honestly I´m lost in the correct implementation. Can you share some example code showing the basics?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I edit my original post with additional info Szczups. Perhaps your solution is add those listeners in each UI screen? Override?

Comment: Hey. My Solution would be to create only one Controller and for each section add listeners (using addEventListener) if you want to catch user input or create methods for allowing manipulation of objects inside each screen from their parent object. 

So in Class Main.as you could have:

`var controller:Controller = new Controller();
//add listeners and all functions beneath

var currentScreen:MovieClip;//assign your screen to this variable.`

And in onFrame function change your UI view depending on user interaction with LeapMotion.

Comment: Can you explain a bit further the currentScreen usage?
The onFrame() function on each screen overrides the original function?

Comment: Any ideas on this?
I´m stuck with this, all my screens works fine on their own, but I can´t create an .exe app, because the controller only works in the first screen...help please!